# Find values which occur in every row for every distinct value in other column of the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, select, distinct

I need a select statement which finds values from Column `B` which occurs in all distinct values for `A`. Meaning in my example it would return:  `x` since `x` occurs in every value of `A`. (1,2,3 and 4)

I don't know which values are in Column `B` so I can't specify this in my query. How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2014?

```
    +---+----+
    | A | B  |
    +---+----+
    | 1 | x  |
    | 2 | x  |
    | 3 | y  |
    | 4 | y  |
    | 3 | x  |
    | 4 | x  |
    +---+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count distinct A grouping by B, and return those where count(distinct A) match.

```
select B, count(distinct A)
from table_AB
group by B
having count(distinct A) = (select count(distinct A) from table_AB);

 B   A 
=== ===
 x   4
```

Comment: this worked out of the box, thank you for the great answer sir

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question with probably multiple answers!

Heres my quick answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    A int,
    B char(1)
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp (A,B)
VALUES (1,'x'),(2,'x'),(3,'y'),(4,'y'),(3,'x'),(4,'x')
GO


WITH ATot AS (
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT A) as 'TotalA'
    FROM #Temp
)
,
BTot AS (
    SELECT B, SUM(A) as 'ValA'
    FROM #Temp
    GROUP BY B
)
SELECT b.B
FROM ATot a
INNER JOIN BTot b ON a.TotalA = b.ValA
```

Comment: thank you sir, unfortunately it didnt work out as expected in sql server. it returned only my column A empty.

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd, I built and ran it in SQL Server 2014 and it works just fine. Maybe you made a translation mistake? I will put them into "A" and "B" column names for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `row_number()` as well

```
drop table #Table1
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([A] int, [B] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([A], [B])
VALUES
    (1, 'x'),
    (2, 'x'),
    (3, 'y'),
    (4, 'y'),
    (3, 'x'),
    (4, 'x'),
    (4, 'y'),
    (5, 'y'),
    (5, 'x')
;

;with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by B order by (select null)) as rn
    from #Table1
    )
    select B from cte 
    where rn = (select max(rn) from cte)
```